# Linked Server to Hana DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sap-hana

I am trying to create a linked server connection from sql-server to Hana DB. I have downloaded the Hana client and all the drivers along with it.

I have tried creating a system DSN and then adding the Hana database using the sp_addlinkedserver and sp_addlinkedsrvlogin procedures. This creates the linked server but when I expand into the server it show no catalogs (basically shows nothing).

Another way I tried was by hitting new linked server and using the SAP Hana MDX Provider and this shows me a default database. However when I expand the tables or views it gives me an error `Cannot obtain the schema rowset "DBSCHEMA_TABLES" for OLE DB provider SAPNEWDBMDXProvider for linked server "NAME"`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Error image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB9i4.jpg

version: Sql-server-17

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: @qwerty added it. thanks!